# Combining request.data and request.query_params in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF to build a RPC-style API where each endpoint can be called with either GET or POST method. So far I got the methods combined nicely:

```
class UpdateUser(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # Do stuff here with request.data
```

Unfortunately POST provides data in `request.data` and GET in `request.query_params`. Is there a way to combine them both into `request.data` or something custom like `request.params`? Parsers doesn't seem to work as they aren't being called on GET requests.

Comment: `http://example.com/test/?param_name=1`

You can get the query paramter value using `request.GET.get('param_name')` and it will return `1`

Comment: It's of course possible to use both `request.data` and `request.query_params` in the `get` function but I would like to avoid that given the added boilerplate.

Comment: Using `request.query_params`  is recommended over `request.GET` in order to make your code more readable ([source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with @jorilallo' comments about using `request.data` inside `get` function.

Alternatively, what you could do is create another function in the view which can have either `request.data` or `request.query_params` as arguments:

```
class UpdateUser(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # POST have request.data 
        return self.process_request(request, request.data)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # GET have request.query_params
        return self.process_request(request, request.query_params)

    def process_request(self, request, data):
        # Do stuff here with data
        # return a response
```

Here, `process_request` function is called from both `post` and `get` methods and relevant `data` is passed as arguments.

Comment: I think this makes a lot of sense in my context and is pretty clean. Thanks, I'll go with this!